# Can I change dynamically innerHTML input code?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a small angular app. One component use `innerHTML` to display content

```
<div [innerHTML]="serviceShared.currentMood"></div>
```

But when I change value of `serviceShared.currentMood` in main component nothing changes. Can I change content dynamically and re-render the component?

**Edit:**

`serviceShared` is a service that provides a value for my `currentMood` which is a string variable that holds HTML code. I change value of that variable by method in my main component. Method changes variable content to one of array`s (string) cell.

Comment: Can you please supply more details around the `serviceShared.currentMood` property and how you are changing it?

Comment: If you're loading asynchronously, you'll need $scope.$apply() after var is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the decorator of your component **ChangeDetectionStrategy** is set to **onPush**